# How to use stdout and stderr child_process in Gulp

Tags: python, flask, gulp, child-process

I use gulp with python flask.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var app = spawn('python', ['app.py']);

gulp.task('runserver', function() {
    app.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });
    app.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });
});
```

But all the logs get to stderr. 
How to adjust the output of the child process to the console?

Comment: Same problem here. Completely insane.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in Node environment, you can use stdout and stderr by following

```
app.stdin.on('readable', () => {
    var chunk = process.stdin.read();

    if (chunk !== null) {
        process.stdout.write(`data: ${chunk}`);
    }
});
app.stdout.write(`${msg}\n`);
```

The process object is a global that provides information about, and control over, the current Node.js process. As a global, it is always available to Node.js applications without using require().

You can reference to these links:

- https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin
- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin